# Using jQuery Form: how to disable AJAX and use the plugin for validation only?

Tags: jquery, forms, plugins

I use the jQuery [Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) only for validation. Is it possible to stop it from sending request on pressing submit button, and just have the HTML form work as if it was a regular HTML form?

Comment: Use a different plugin, like [this one](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: You may be better served with the validation plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the form to submit as normal (ie. synchronously), then you're not using the right plugin. Remove the form plugin and use [jQuery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) instead.